# Lombok installation failed on IBM Rational Application Developer

Tags: eclipse, lombok, ibm-rad

I try to install Lombok on IBM Rational Application Developer and I don't succed. I've made all the steps that are necessary for an eclipse based IDE, but IDE can't start right know. If I delete the -javaagent argument that referes lombok from eclipse.ini, the IDE it will start again, but the lombok will not be ready for development.

I have the following exception in .log file from .metadata folder:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-06 15:59:10.026
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lombok.launch.PatchFixesHider$LombokDeps
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Product.addLombokNotesToEclipseAboutDialog(Product.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Product.getProperty(Product.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ProductProperties.getAppName(ProductProperties.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ProductInfo.getAppName(ProductInfo.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getAppName(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1038)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.launch.PatchFixesHider$LombokDeps
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:707)
    ... 22 more
```

I've already read all the suggestions from stackoverflow/github but nothing worked. I will appreciate any idea :)

Thank you :)

Comment: Since you are using RAD, not Eclipse, you should replace your **eclipse** tag with an **ibm-rad** tag.

Comment: RAD it's an Eclipse based IDE, this is the purpose that i've put eclipse tag. I've added the ibm-rad tag, also.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the stacktrace correctly, the code fails where Lombok tries to patch the info screen to show that Lombok is installed correctly. It seems that RAD does not contain the same code here.

Please [register a bug report](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues).

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: Hello! I've opened a new ticket. Maybe you'll find a resolution. If you have any question, you can find me here :)